# How can I "mock" the UI of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am trying to take screenshots of my iOS app. Before taking a screenshot, I need to get the app to an appropriate state. To get to an appropriate state, a lot of swiping is required.

This would have been fine if I have actual devices, but I don't. So I need to perform swipes on a simulator using a trackpad. I find this very hard, and sometimes I can't swipe properly so the gesture is not recognised.

I thought of using the UI Testing library to programmatically perform swipes. However, my app is actually a game, and random events happen. Writing code to handle these random events would not be worth the time. It would be best if I am in control of the swiping.

I have also thought of adding buttons on the UI of the app. When they are pressed a swipe is simulated. Then I can just click those buttons instead of swiping with my trackpad, which is way easier. However, these buttons will then appear on the screenshot, which I obviously don't want users to see.

Also note that I can't use a tap gesture recogniser as a replacement for the swipe gesture recognisers, because I need to detect swipes in all four directions and do different things depending on the direction.

Essentially, how can I perform a "swipe" more easily on the simulator? It would be great if I can do this by pressing keys on my keyboard, or maybe there is a feature in Xcode that allows me to do this which I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you automate the UI test.

Recording a test from live actions is a standard Xcode UI test feature. Fastlane is the icing on the cake to automate the capture of screenshots too.

Fastlane has the tools to automatically run a UI test and capture screenshots in all device resolutions. You can even record the actions by recording a UI test and play it back.

Check it out here:

[Fastlane Screenshot](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot)

Even if you do not wish to use Fastlane, you can record the gestures in a unit test and have it pause.

Comment: As I said, my app is a game, and random things happen, I can't just use a predefined set of gestures. It would be great if I were in control.

Comment: What's the precondition for taking a screenshot? You can test various on screen things. I suggest, perhaps otherwise for automatic runs, you start with the same seed for rand() to make it predictable? e.g. does a 'bag guy' have to appear or something? Using the same seed would be more consistent.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like it would work, but I still would like some control over it. I will wait for more answers for other alternatives. If there isn't then I will accept this.